# Using an API in Maven

Tags: java, api, maven

I have an API for Java that I've been messing around with. It is a maven project. I want to be able to test that it works. Is there a way I can make a new Java project and using maven to import that API into my project?

(Not that it should matter but I am using IntelliJ)

Example:

API is CommandAPI. Now I want to make a "CommandAPITester" project where I import the API using maven and play around with some tests.

Thank you!

Please let me know if you need any more info to answer the question.

Comment: Yes that is possible. The easiest way would be to just use the `test` source set to implement the tests, since this avoids handling artifact resolution. A tutorial on how to do this can, for example, be found [over at `javaguides.com`](https://www.javaguides.net/2018/07/junit-getting-started-guide.html).

Comment: Do not Junit 4 anymore it's really time to move to JUnit JUpiter (aka JUnit 5)...  https://junit.org/junit5/